How to compare tcl variable by "otherValuePtr" instead of "bytes"
4As we know Tcl_obj is a struct as picture shown.
And for example: "set var 1,  if { $var == 1 } { puts "success" }"
And "var" is a Tcl_obj, tcl command "==" is match "bytes" in Tcl_Obj type, if var's bytes is 1, then it will go into { puts "success"}.  But I want to match the "otherValuePtr" in Tcl_Obj struct. if otherValuePtr is 1, then it will go into { puts "success"}.  How did I implement it?
I read the c code in ./generic/tclCompile.c, but I have no result, so sad.

Help to resolve this problem.

You can't in general.
The contents of the union in the internalRep field (the otherValuePtr is part of that) are determined by the typePtr. You can only compare two of them when both values' types are ones that you understand completely (typically because you issued the type). Otherwise, the official ways to compare them are either to use Tcl_GetStringFromObj() on each to get a UTF-8 representation and compare those, or to demand that the values conform to some other model (an operation that is permitted to fail) and compare those (e.g., you do Tcl_GetIntFromObj() on each). If you aren't the owner of the type, it's very likely that you won't know how to correctly extract it from the union; Tcl has fairly complex internal models for some of its types (especially in Tcl 9.0), and will and does change the implementations of its internal types from version to version. They are not a stable API, but an implementation detail.
The standard recommendation is to design your types so that the conversion from internal representation to string is stable (usually easy for things like lists and integers) or so that the internal representation is always derived from the string so that you never need to serialize anything in the first place.
However, if your code already owns the type concerned, you already know how to extract the real internal representation from the internalRep field and what to do with it at that point. You need to know that in order to write a type implementation after all! You just can't safely do that for others' types.

Thanks for your reply, Donal.  Yes for I do understand the type of "otherValuePtr", because I updated the "typePtr" to my type, and update Tcl_ObjType element (include name, Tcl FreeInternalRepProc, Tcl_DupInternalRepProc, Tcl_UpdateStringProc, Tcl_SetFromAnyProc), After that, The otherValuePtr will assign as my object like "internalRep.otherValuePtr = (void *) yingjieObj".

And I implement Tcl_GetStringFromYingjieObj(), but I don't know how to use them to compare like " typePtr of var1 is yingjieType, and otherValuePtr is 1024, typePtr of var2 is yingjieType, and otherValuePtr is 1024, if { $var1 == $var2 } { puts "xxx" }", it could get result "xxx".  And we can expand to lsearch or other commands.

There is a Tcl_RegisterObjType  in TclObj.c file. Could I register my type and do something to implement it ?
